# Adding padding to gRaphael charts?

Tags: javascript, raphael, graphael

Altough very little documention available online, I have been able to work out how to produce the below shown graph using [Raphael.js](http://g.raphaeljs.com) and the [gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com) addon. I am altough quite confused about how I can style my tags that appear during hovering onto each data point. How do I add some padding around the text?

Here's how it looks right now:

[image]

**The code:**

```
var r = Raphael("graphcontainer");
var linec = r.linechart(10,10,300,220,[1,2,3,4,5],[10,20,15,35,30], {colors:["#009933"], symbol:"circle", smooth: false}); 

linec.hoverColumn(function () {
    this.tags = r.set();
    for (var i = 0, ii = this.y.length; i < ii; i++) {          
        this.tags.push(r.tag(this.x + 10, this.y[i], this.values[i]+"tkr", 0, 0).insertBefore(this).attr([{ fill: "#fff" }, { fill: this.symbols[i].attr("fill") }]));
    }
}, function () {
    this.tags && this.tags.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with axis.

You may need to get the Raphael object and turn it into a jQuery object, and then style via jQuery.

Something like this:

```
for (var i = 0, ii = this.y.length; i < ii; i++) {          
   this.tags.push(r.tag(this.x + 10, this.y[i], this.values[i]+"tkr", 0, 0).insertBefore(this).attr([{ fill: "#fff" }, { fill: this.symbols[i].attr("fill") }]));
   var $jQueryObject = $(this.tags.node);
   $jQueryObject.css('font-size', '30px')
}
```

Please note that not all CSS attributes work with this solution. I am not sure why, if someone  has some comments on this, will be much appreciated.

Some adjustments may be needed. Let us know your experience  ;)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi mb, i just wondering what is the rendered html tag  when the tooltip tag appears on page ? Since i tried your suggestion but it does not work, so i think catching the tag when the whole page is loaded should be ok